# How to delete a return carriage on R

Tags: r, data-import

I would like to import data into R from a file where some records are split in two. The data comes from a database export and it is very likely that users have entered a carriage return in a text field. The records were correctly integrated into the database since it was received in XML format. The problem arises at export where the carriage return is restored in a txt file in CSV2 format

Here is an illustrative fictional example

"a bumblebee"; "a buzzard"; "a duck"; "a canary"; "a carp"; "a deer"; "a chamois" "A "bird"; "a horse"; "a dog"; "a hen"; "a cat"; **"a"**

**"fish"; "a bee"**
"a lamb"; "an eagle"; "a lark"; "an ostrich"; "a bar"; "a woodcock"; "a buffalo".

The second record is cut at the sixth field, **"a"** in line 2 then in line 3 **"fish"; "a bee".**

Would you have a solution (other than manually deleting carriage returns) to be able to import this type of data correctly into R.

Thank you in advance! 
Marie.

Comment: Please edit the question with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.). This will allow us to reproduce your data exactly as you have it.

Comment: I can see another problem as `"A "lamb";` seems to be `"A lamb";`. Is it typo at your end?

Comment: @Rui The OP is referring to data on disk not a table already in R, right?

Comment: @Frank I didn't understand it like that but maybe you're right, yes. In which case bash commands (or equivalent) seem more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `readLines` and `dplyr` package can be achieved. Since, OP has not provided clear rule to decide completeness of row hence the below solution assumes that a `row` is complete if it ends with `;`.

**A)** Solution for content of `filedata.txt`:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(fileText = readLines("filedata.txt"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

tidy_text <- df %>% mutate(IsComplete = grepl(";$",df$fileText)) %>%
  group_by(SameRow = cumsum(lag(IsComplete, default=1))) %>%
  summarise(fileText = paste0(trimws(fileText), collapse=" "))
```

**Result:**

```
tidy_text$fileText
#[1] "\"a bumblebee\"; \"a buzzard\"; \"a duck\"; \"a canary\"; \"a carp\"; \"a deer\"; \"a chamois\" \"A \"bird\"; \"a horse\";"                                
#[2] "\"a dog\"; \"a hen\"; \"a cat\"; \"a\" \"fish\"; \"a bee\" \"A lamb\"; \"an eagle\"; \"a lark\"; \"an ostrich\"; \"a bar\"; \"a woodcock\"; \"a buffalo\";"
```

**Data:**
Content of `filedata.txt`

```
"a bumblebee"; "a buzzard"; "a duck"; "a canary"; "a carp"; "a deer"; "a chamois" "A "bird"; "a horse";
"a dog"; "a hen"; "a cat"; "a"
"fish"; "a bee"
"A lamb"; "an eagle"; "a lark"; "an ostrich"; "a bar"; "a woodcock"; "a buffalo";
```

**B)** Solution for content of `filedata2.txt`. Each row/observation starts with `extraction;`

```
df <- data.frame(fileText = readLines("filedata2.txt"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
tidy_text2 <- df %>% mutate(IsComplete = lead(grepl("^extraction;.*", df$fileText),
               default = TRUE)) %>%
               group_by(SameRow = cumsum(lag(IsComplete, default=1))) %>%
               summarise(fileText = paste0(trimws(fileText), collapse=" "))
```

**Result#2:** Data has been summarized in 3 observations.

```
tidy_text2
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#    SameRow fileText                                                                                 
#      <int> <chr>                                                                                    
# 1       1 extraction;xxxx bvbbv ncnncbvbbv;fdrggggqggqhh;-276654.00;;-657321.00                    
# 2       2 extraction;fhdh bvbbv dsmfdjjf fdhhhhdf;hqshfdsjf sdkfjdfjkdkfj ;;-547743.00,-432743.00  
# 3       3 extraction;shdfgqs bvbbv dsmfdjjf fdhhhhdf;hqshfdsjf sdkfjdfjkdkfj;;-547743.00;-432743.00
```

**Data:** Content of `filedata2.txt`

```
extraction;xxxx bvbbv ncnncbvbbv;fdrggggqggqhh;-276654.00;;-657321.00
extraction;fhdh bvbbv dsmfdjjf
fdhhhhdf;hqshfdsjf sdkfjdfjkdkfj
;;-547743.00,-432743.00 
extraction;shdfgqs bvbbv dsmfdjjf fdhhhhdf;hqshfdsjf sdkfjdfjkdkfj;;-547743.00;-432743.00
```

Comment: thanks for your proposition.
We tried on our data but it doesn't work.                                                                                 
Here is another example:          
                                                                        
a bumblebee;a buzzard;a duck;a canary
a carp;a deer;a
chamois; a bird
a horse;a dog;a hen;a cat                                                                                             
 
As a result, we should have: 3 observations and 4 variables but the second observation is split in the 3rd variable.

Comment: @Marie You can tweak my answer so that `in-complete` row criteria matches to your need, but basic logic will remain same. BTW, how are you deciding if a `row` is complete? Your 2nd example has added more confusion.

Comment: with number of semi-colon. It's a french csv file

Comment: @Marie Exactly that's what my solution is based on. It looks for last character in a line as `;` if that is no present then it assumes that line is partial and adds that line to next line and so on.

Comment: @Marie May be it is worth adding say (10-20) lines from your file in question. Please add those lines as-is. It will help to find solution.

Comment: ";" is only a separator and not the last caracter of an observation

Comment: @Marie Okay, that makes sense. What is last character of an observation then?

Comment: please, do you know how i can dowload the txt file with more lines?

Comment: last caracter is carriage return

Comment: @Marie just `carriage return` will not be sufficient to decide if a line is complete or not because `carriage return` is present for partial lines as well. You can simply `copy` content from txt file and `paste` it in question.

Comment: here is another example which fit our data:     

extraction;xxxx bvbbv ncnncbvbbv;fdrggggqggqhh;-276654.00;;-657321.00
extraction;fhdh bvbbv dsmfdjjf fdhhhhdf;hqshfdsjf sdkfjdfjkdkfj;;-547743.00,-432743.00
extraction;shdfgqs 
bvbbv dsmfdjjf fdhhhhdf;hqshfdsjf sdkfjdfjkdkfj;;-547743.00;-432743.00

Comment: and the result we want to reach : 

extraction;xxxx bvbbv ncnncbvbbv;fdrggggqggqhh;-276654.00;;-657321.00
extraction;fhdh bvbbv dsmfdjjf fdhhhhdf;hqshfdsjf ;;-547743.00;-432743.00
extraction;shdfgqs bvbbv dsmfdjjf fdhhhhdf;hqshfdsjf ;;547743.0;432743.00

Hope it's more clear. Thks

Comment: @Marie Does that mean every row starts with `extraction;`? And row which doesnt starts with `extraction;` is continuation of previous row. Please confirm.

Comment: @Marie I have updated my answer for 2nd file data as well.

Comment: @Marie Glad to know it helped. You can accept answer by clicking on `tick` symbol in left of answer box.